# Run sqlcmd with WScript.shell - waitonreturn does not start

Tags: vbscript, sqlcmd

I want to start a sqlcmd-script from a vbscript. 
What I and what works is:

```
return = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("cmd /c ""sqlcmd -S localhost -i --Path and Filename Script--.sql -o --Path and Filename Log--.log -b""")
```

My problem: if I now add the parameters for `intWindowStyle` and `bWaitOnReturn`, the script does not run anymore.

Example:

```
return = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Run("cmd /c ""sqlcmd -S localhost -i --Path and Filename Script--.sql -o --Path and Filename Log--.log -b""", 0, True)
```

`WScript.Echo` says that return = 1.

I call the VBScript via batch with `cscript //nologo --script--`.

Comment: There's no reason why `sqlcmd` should run correctly when `Run` is invoked with default values for the 2nd and 3rd parameters, but not when `Run` is invoked with explicit values for those parameters. What do you get when you invoke `.Run("cmd /k ""...""", 1, True)`?

Comment: If I do `.Run("cmd /k ""...""", 1, True)` he opens up a new console telling me he can not find the function `...`.

Another thing I found out: If I change the `True` to `false` he is starting the sqlcmd script.

Comment: I thought it was obvious that you need to replace the ellipsis (`...`) that I put there for brevity with the actual command you intend to run. But apparently not. So, replace the three dots in that statement with your `sqlcmd` commandline. What do you get when running that?

Comment: Thank you, that brought the result I searched for. The console told me sqlcmd could not open the sql file. I still can't see the reason why he did that without the parameter, but ok. BTW: How can I mark your answer as correct (if needed) :-)

Comment: It's a comment with debugging instructions, not an actual answer to your question. And I doubt that the command ran successfully when you omitted the other parameters. Without the 3rd parameter set to `True` the `Run` method just returns immediately while the command is executed in the background.

Comment: If you update your question with the error message that is displayed in the command window we might be able to help you solve the actual problem.